# Makefile problem with conditional used in define used in commands part of a rule

Tags: makefile

I have a section of makefile that has this sort of structure:

```
bob:
ifdef DEBUG
    @echo running
endif
    @echo chug chug chug
ifdef DEBUG
    @echo done
endif    

bobit:
    @echo "before"
    @make bob
    @echo "after"
```

I'm simplifying greatly here, all the echo's are actually non trivial blocks of commands and there is more conditional stuff, but this captures the essence of my problem.

For technical reasons I don't want to get into right now, I need to get rid of that submake, but because the echo's represent nontrivial amounts of code I don't want to just copy and past the body of bob in place of the submake.

Ideally what I'd like to do is something like this

```
define BOB_BODY 
ifdef DEBUG
    @echo running
endif
    @echo chug chug chug
ifdef DEBUG
    @echo done
endif
endef

bob:
    $(BOB_BODY)

bobit:
    @echo "before"
    $(BOB_BODY)
    @echo "after"
```

Unfortunately the conditionals seem to be shafting me, they produce "ifdef: Command not found" errors, I tried getting around this with various combinations of eval and call, but can't seem to figure out a way to get it to work.

How do I make this work? and is it even the right way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have fixed this is to use bash conditionals instead, which actually makes a certain amount of sense since we are playing with commands and not make rules.

So my ideal solution from above becomes something like

```
define BOB_BODY
    @if [[ -n "$(DEBUG)" ]]; then \
        echo running; \
    fi;
    @echo chug chug chug
    @if [[ -n "$(DEBUG)" ]]; then \
        echo done; \
    fi
endef
```

bob:
    $(BOB_BODY)

bobit:
    @echo "before"
    $(BOB_BODY)
    @echo "after"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the order of ifdef/define:

```
ifdef DEBUG
  define BOB_BODY 
    @echo running
    @echo chug chug chug
    @echo done
  endef
else 
  define BOB_BODY 
    @echo chug chug chug
  endef
endif
```

**UPDATE**

```
define CHUG
  @echo chug chug chug
endef

ifdef DEBUG
  define BOB_BODY 
    @echo running
    $(CHUG)
    @echo done
  endef
else 
  define BOB_BODY 
    $(CHUG)
  endef
endif
```

Comment: the problem with that approach is it duplicates the "chug chug chug" bit which in the original makefile was 30 lines of stuff